# Lex matching doesn't enter recursive rule as expected

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to match words between `#` characters. Here is my attempt:

```
init : (TEXT | HASH | placeholder) init? EOF ;
placeholder : HASH lexeme HASH ;
lexeme : LEXEME;

HASH : '#' ;
LEXEME : [a-zA-Z0-9-_]+ ;
TEXT : ~'#'+ ;
```

My input string: `"The good text with a #LEXEME#followed# by hashes of death#############"`

And the resulting `ParseTree`:

[image]

I'm expecting the "followed" word to be parsed as a `TEXT` in the next recursive `init` but it looks like it's parsed in the same `init` iteration, thus not recognized. This happens every time a pattern like `#letters#letters#` is encountered.

How do I solve this?

Comment: According to your grammar, `LEXEME`s are only allowed inside `placeholder`s. In order to be parsed as part of an `init`, "followed" would have to be a `TEXT`, which it is not.

Comment: Why is it not a `TEXT`? `~'#'+` means anything that doesn't contain "#" am I right? Then why "followed" doesn't match?

Comment: Yes, it matches the pattern for `TEXT`, but it also matches the one for `LEXEME` and it can't be two tokens at once. When multiple lexer rules can match the current input and would produce tokens of the same length, the one that's defined first wins.

Comment: I don't ask it to match `LEXEME` the other possibility is `placeholder`. But there one thing I don't understand even before that: after the "#LEXEME#" string has been recognized as a `HASH LEXEME HASH`, why does it not just exit the `(TEXT | HASH | placeholder)` and go through another `init`? The "followed" word is being parsed in the same `init` iteration and I don't get why

Comment: Always print out the tokens generated by the lexer and verify exactly what you expect to see. The TestRig tree doesn't print out what the token types are--it's an inadequate tool! Remember: the lexer works completely independently of a parser. You then see the lexer is returning token type=2 (the LEXEME rule) for "followed". The only time the lexer returns token type=3 (the TEXT rule) is for the string "The good text with a " because it has spaces. Antlr lexers match the largest string always. Then, if there are two rules that match the same string, the first one listed in your grammar "wins".

Comment: That makes totally sense @kaby76 thanks for this!

Comment: Do you think I would need to use sublexers in order to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the `#`s to mark the start and stop of your `placeholder`s (aka `LEXEME`s).  You could do that by breaking the grammar into a Lexer grammar and a Parser grammar:

```
lexer grammar HashLexer
    ;

HASH: '#' -> mode(PLACEHOLDER_MODE);
TEXT: ~'#'+;

mode PLACEHOLDER_MODE
    ;
LEXEME:    [a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+;
HASH_TERM: '#' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

```
parser grammar HashParser
    ;
options {
    tokenVocab = HashLexer;
}

init:        (TEXT | placeholder)* EOF;
placeholder: HASH LEXEME? HASH_TERM;
```

When I try to parse your input `"The good text with a #LEXEME#followed# by hashes of death#############"` however, I get the following token stream:

```
[@0,0:20='The good text with a ',<TEXT>,1:0]
[@1,21:21='#',<HASH>,1:21]
[@2,22:27='LEXEME',<LEXEME>,1:22]
[@3,28:28='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:28]
[@4,29:36='followed',<TEXT>,1:29]
[@5,37:37='#',<HASH>,1:37]
[@6,39:40='by',<LEXEME>,1:39]
[@7,42:47='hashes',<LEXEME>,1:42]
[@8,49:50='of',<LEXEME>,1:49]
[@9,52:56='death',<LEXEME>,1:52]
[@10,57:57='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:57]
[@11,58:58='#',<HASH>,1:58]
[@12,59:59='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:59]
[@13,60:60='#',<HASH>,1:60]
[@14,61:61='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:61]
[@15,62:62='#',<HASH>,1:62]
[@16,63:63='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:63]
[@17,64:64='#',<HASH>,1:64]
[@18,65:65='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:65]
[@19,66:66='#',<HASH>,1:66]
[@20,67:67='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:67]
[@21,68:68='#',<HASH>,1:68]
[@22,69:69='#',<HASH_TERM>,1:69]
[@23,70:70='\n',<TEXT>,1:70]
[@24,71:70='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

The `#` after `followed` pushes us into the `PLACEHOLDER_MODE` so `" by hashes of death"` is Lexed in `PLACEHOLDER` mode and generates recognition errors as it does not match the `LEXEME` rule.  And you get the following parse tree:

[image]

This seems the correct interpretation of your input (assuming that `#`s act like `(` and `)` to bracket some input, then you're going to get situations like this when they're not matched up correctly.  The only solution to that would be to relax the grammar quite a bit and handle more of the validation in a a listener/visitor.